# Remote Bolts unable to Ack messages

Tags: apache-storm

We have a multi-node storm cluster and we are using Guaranteed processing of Storm for making sure that events are processed exactly once.

Our topology consists of a spout and multiple bolts (50). We have set the number of acker equivalent to the number of workers. From our logs we can identify that bolts are acking but the spout may not receive them. We do notice that the spout is receiving the ack from bolts which are on the same node. We believe the issue to be either network connectivity or ack timing out.

Any idea what is cause of why the remote bolts are unable to ack and how do we debug this? Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked `iptables` or any similar firewalls (`security groups` if you are on `AWS`)?

Comment: We checked the iptables and firewalls, everything seems to be fine. Any idea if we can turn on some logging which tells the failure to send ack.